# Data Loader - Custom Settings Import

Tags: data-loader, customsetting

I am trying to import data into custom settings via data loader.

I am getting an error during insert operation stating

```
"Required fields are missing: [Name]
"
```

If it is a custom object I can set the Name field as auto increment.

I am unable to see such option for Name field in custom settings.

Can someone suggest as to what should be done in this case ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats not an option for custom settings.  You access custom settings by their name, so you really want to make the name something unique and that is descriptive of the record so you have a way to access it.

Answer (score 2):

The name is the key, and is required (like Lastname is required on Contact) - so you need to set it something unique...you would need to create that unique key to map to the Name field in your dataset prior to loading it